# Transfer data from DB2 to Oracle

Tags: oracle, db2, migration

I want to transfer data from an old DB2 system to a new Oracle database.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to use the Oracle Gateway for DB2 which can be used to create an Oracle database link to the DB2 database. Then use a SQL script to "pull" all the data from each table in turn by

```
insert into oracle_table select * from db2_table@dblink;
```

Answer (score 0):

You export the data from Db2 and import into Oracle. There are considerations such as big-Endian, Unix vs Windows etc.

Here is a link:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0505tham/

Answer (score 0):

There's a dedicated migration tool that should meet your needs:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/db2-084087.html

Another common solution to migrate data is export each table in a CSV file and then import each CSV file in the new database tables.
To import CSV into Oracle tables you can use the Sql Loader utility (that comes with Oracle), with this useful [tool](https://code.google.com/p/oracle-csv-loader/) to automatically create the script needed.